# convert small to capital on keypressevent using javascript

Tags: javascript

How to convert capital latter when type small latter when fired `onkeypress` event? My Function is working in Internet Explorer but not working in Google Chrome and FireFox.

```
function Capital(evt) [
    key = (evt || window.event) ? evt.keyCode : evt.which;
    if (key >= 97 && key <= 122) {
        if ((evt || window.event)) evt.keyCode = evt.keyCode - 32;
        else evt.which = evt.which - 32;
    }
}
```

this function called in `onkeypress="Capital(event)"`

Comment: Take a look at .toUpperCase()

Comment: In Mozilla browsers, [keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/KeyboardEvent) is deprecated and read only.

Comment: I was about to post a comment saying this won't work even in IE, but actually it really works. I'm amazed =D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't need JS at all, just set `text-transform: uppercase;` for your element.

Comment: This won't make the actual underlying text uppercase, it is only useful for display purposes

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough. Pass the element to your function and convert .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function convertCase(elem)
    {
        elem.value = elem.value.toUpperCase();
    }
</script>
<input onkeypress="convertCase(this);" type="text" id="txt1" />
```

Comment: Thanks But This is not a proper way because when this function used me that time i am typing like 'a' that time display for at least second a then convert to A.

Comment: Dont really understand what you mean by whatever you had wanted to mean . Be specific .

Comment: This will, however, mess up with cursor position, forcing you to use some get and set cursor function, once user starts typping in the middle of the text.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('my-ok').onkeypress = function() {
  var self = this
  setTimeout(function() {
    self.value = self.value.toUpperCase()
  }, 0)
}
```

```html
<input id='my-ok' type="text">
```

[Event and timing](http://javascript.info/tutorial/events-and-timing-depth#give-the-browser-time-for-job)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of writing script on keypress i suggest to write it on blur event like below.

```
 window.onload = function () {
            var textBx = document.getElementById("txt");

            textBx.onblur = function () {
                this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
            };
        };
```

Comment: That's not up to you. Maybe the OP wants it to happen as the user is typing. The other answer accomplishes this just fine.

Comment: Thanks But This is not a proper way because when this function used me that time i am typing like 'a' that time display for at least second a then convert to A.