# Change event input character

Tags: javascript, keypress, keyevent

Is it possible to simply change the character, that is written in the text field, by changing some of the `event` object properties? For example, I want to hide password characters from command:
User types:

> login username password

I want to appear:

> login username `********`

And save password to variable. So, i want to remap any key to `*` once the `textbox.value` contains `/^login [a-zA-Z0-9]+ /`.

**Edit** - respectfully to comments speaking of misunderstanding my question:
Because all above happens within a little command line client, and there may be multiple commands, that I may want to protect by `*` obfuscation, no thoughts of using `<input type="password" />` are acceptable!

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using `<input type="password" />`?

Comment: You could just use a password field assuming you are using JS on html?

Comment: Man, I thought that if I write `login username password` it will be enough obvious, that we are talking about command line!

Comment: No it is absolutely not obvious. You mention text field. How would that be command line?

Comment: it's probably a better idea to use separate input fields.

Comment: No, its not. I need to protect multiple commands (like registering user with password) where some passwords occur!

Comment: Well, I used "command" word just before the command example. Do you login to stack overwlow using some text, that begins with "login"? No? May be that is what makes my login different from normal form authentication.

Comment: How would the script guess when it should start capturing your input and replace what you type with `*`?

Comment: Once the command entered reaches the regexp I've posted in my question, the capture starts. When the input value is not sufficient any more, the replacing stops.

Comment: His code is bad indeed and that is why I voted it down and posted the jsfiddle, to make others see that that way is wrong. You're right with cutting and other madness, but for simplicity, I expect passwords to be typed char by char in order to be hidden. I know a way how to handle any edits, but it is not as simple as changing the event input key.

Comment: @TomášZato I've built up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3YkXm/) for you. It's not perfect, but does the job with _one_ known command like `login`. Also there's a problem with FF and `BACKSPACE`, but maybe you can develope the code further.

Comment: Thank you for your code. I've already developed very similar code, but didn't dare to post it as my own answer unless its perfect. I achieved to make backspace work correctly in firefox, and I will fix it in your fiddle. I use `this.selectionStart;` to determine, where the characters are written (will not work in IE).

Comment: I had separate `IF` for deleting characters, by the way.

Comment: @TomášZato I've improved the code, now it can recognize a command from a list. Also the snippet is added as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet does the trick. It's not perfect, but can be developed further.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var cmdfield = document.getElementById('cmdfield'),
        commandString = '',
        cmds = '(login|logout)',
        rex = new RegExp('^' + cmds + ' [a-zA-Z0-9]+ (\\w*)'),
        keyPress = function (e) {       
            if ((e.which > 64 && e.which < 123) || (e.which > 47 && e.which < 58) || e.which === 32) {
                commandString += String.fromCharCode(e.which);
                this.value = commandString.replace(rex, function (m, a, b) {
                    var command = m.split(' ')[0],
                        param = m.split(' ')[1],
                        len = b.length;
                    if (len > 0) {
                        return command + ' ' + param + ' ' + new Array(len + 1).join('*');
                    }
                    if (len === 0) {
                        return command + ' ' + param + ' ';
                    }
                });
            }
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        },
        keyDown = function (e) {
            if (e.which === 8) {
                commandString = commandString.substring(0, commandString.length - 1);
                e.stopPropagation();
                return;
            }
            if (!((e.which > 64 && e.which < 122) || (e.which > 47 && e.which < 58) || e.which === 32)) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            return;
        };
    cmdfield.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown, false);
    cmdfield.addEventListener('keypress', keyPress, false);
}
```

`cmds` is a pipe-separated list of all words, which should have one visible parameter after it, and after that parameter there will be stars on the textfield until to next space. If the command is not on the list, the third parameter won't be obfuscated.

If you want to detect more than one occurrence of these kind of combinations on the same line, just use the regexp below:

```
rex = new RegExp('\\b' + cmd + ' [a-zA-Z0-9]+ (\\w*)', 'g'),
```

The real value of the "command text" is stored in `commandString`.

Notice that this implementation is not protected against text editing by mouse or clipboard. Also when run on Firefox, <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> won't empty the field before user starts write again.

A live demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3YkXm/1/).

---

**EDIT**

Actually your question was about overriding `Event` object properties. In general those properties are read-only, and can't be modified. However, there seems to be an exception for the rule: at least IE9 allows modifying of the `window.event.keyCode` within `onkeypress` handler. The snippet below really works in IE9 when calling inline `onkeypress=capitalize()`, but not with handler attached by `addEventListener()`.

```
function capitalize() {
    key = window.event.keyCode;
    if (key > 96 && key < 123) {
        window.event.keyCode = window.event.keyCode - 32;
    }
    return window.event.keyCode;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this will inspire me.

Comment: I accepted this, though it is not an answer to my question - how to change actual pressed character. I believe this is not directly possible, though may be done by `window.dispatchEvent()`.

Comment: I've seen that working only in IE and `onkeypress`, I'm afraid this is the only cross-browser way to do it. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14766547/1169519) a question with the code, which works for IE.

Comment: It surelly must only work with onkeypress, but fact that only in IE, the key ID is not read-only means bad news for me.

Comment: @TomášZato I've added some info to my answer about the read-only issue in IE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `input type=password`, but for any other reasons, the below script will do the job for you.

```
var field = document.getElementById("password")
var val= "";
field.onkeydown = function(evt){
    val+= String.fromCharCode(evt.keyCode)      
    this.value = val.replace(/./g,"*");      
   document.getElementById("hiddenfieldPassword").value = val; // Hidden Field to store the password.
  return false;   
}
```

Comment: Try this with arrow keys, and other non character keys. Try this with SHIFT - **case will be ignored**. Finally, do not forget that the **command entered must not disappear**!

Comment: I made some JS fiddle to show you, that your code does not really work - http://jsfiddle.net/vS2ZX/1/